# Python Mysqld: After reinstall, only works if variable tuple has trailing comma

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I just reinstalled Python 2.7 and mysql-python (using the windows installer https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5).

I now have an issue that I didn't used to have:

```
import MySQLdb
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, var_tuple)
return cursor.fetchall()
```

This code fails if var_tuple is missing a trailing comma:

(my_var) fails, but
(my_var, ) is good to go.

This worked a-ok before and is running great in my production environment.

Adding trailing commas to all my many many statements is not an option. As I said, this is running great in production, and I need to fix the root cause.

IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

Again, this EXACT code with a single variable and no trailing comma is working right now in my production environment. It worked yesterday in development before reinstalling. We're not talking one line that may have changed, but hundreds of select statements that do this. And again, changing hundreds of select statements instead of the root cause is not an option. It's certainly not a good one.

Comment: `(my_var)` is *not* a tuple

Comment: Whatever it is, it works in production and worked before. I need to get it working again.

Comment: Maybe that before `my_var` actually contained a tuple and not anymore. Anyway `(my_var)` is no different from `my_var` and nothing will change that except a major rewrite of python's grammar. If you need a 1-long tuple, write it `(my_var,)`.

Comment: do you have the same versions on production and dev machines?

Comment: It was possible to pass a single value instead of a tuple in older versions of MySQLdb, however that was a bug and is not valid according to dbpi2, so this [has been corrected](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/commit/7dd57dcf5f50271d12a6c6bba3d3ca2b3a59348c?diff=split#diff-4236fcc920ba29148bd3899489d18f0cL183) in 1.2.5

Comment: Thank you! Installing mysql-python 1.2.4 (not 1.2.5) solved the issue. I'll be moving to Google Cloud and whatever they are running still works without a trailing comma. So no need to use the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mata!

Installing mysql-python 1.2.4 (not 1.2.5) solved the issue. Apparently this was a 'bug' that they decided to fix.

I'll be moving to Google Cloud, and their version still works without a trailing comma. So I also don't want to use the latest version on Dev.